# What is the best way to rewrite this code (Line is too long)

Tags: ruby

I am checking my code with rubocop and get the warning for this code:

```
def questions_from_time_by_page(t, pagesize, page)
  "#{@base_url}questions?pagesize=#{pagesize}&page=#{page}&fromdate=#{t}&site=stackoverflow&key=#{@key}"
end
```

> lib/stackify.rb:99:81: C: Line is too long. [108/80]
>         "#{@base_url}questions?pagesize=#{pagesize}&page=#{page}&fromdate=#{t}&site=stackoverflow&key=#{@key}"

What is the best way to rewrite it?

Split line to multiple lines ?

```
def questions_from_time_by_page(t, pagesize, page)
  "#{@base_url}questions?pagesize=#{pagesize}&page=#{page}" + 
  "&fromdate=#{t}&site=stackoverflow&key=#{@key}"
end
```

Or may be there is a better way?

Comment: To be honest, I ignore these warnings about long lines. Splitting them up does not seem to be worth the trouble since you can easily introduce new errors.

Comment: If that's in Rails, you could go with route helpers, they allow to encode some arguments in a query string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `to_query` on Hash which will take care of url encoding etc.  So maybe something like this:

```
params = {
  :a => "http://google.com",
  :b => 123
}
url = "http://example.com?#{params.to_query}"
```

This produces `"http://example.com?a=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com&b=123"`

Tell me if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

G.B. answer is a pragmatic way to solve your problem.

But if you want to keep your string you could use `""\` to make multiline strings

e.g.

```
"#{@base_url}questions?pagesize=#{pagesize}&page=#{page}"\
"&fromdate=#{t}&site=stackoverflow&key=#{@key}"
```